# android app unfortunately stopped

Tags: android, android-intent

I am new to android programming
I wrote a program in which I created a button..clicking on which I should navigate to other page
I am not getting any error but when I launch the application opens and immediately it says "unfortunately stopped" and closes the program.

**this is my code**

```
    package com.hotel;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;

    public class HotelActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
        Button btnClick=null, button1;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_hotel);
            button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
            btnClick.setOnClickListener(this);

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_hotel, menu);
            return true;
        }


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(R.id.button1==v.getId())

             {
                Intent i= new Intent(HotelActivity.this,MenuActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }   
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }


    }
```

**and this is its repective xml file**

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".HotelActivity" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="162dp"
            android:text="@string/start" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

**this is the second page's code**

```
    package com.hotel;

    import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.Toast;


    @SuppressLint("ShowToast") public class MenuActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener{
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */

        ListView lv;


        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.menu);

            lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.menu_settings);
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        }


     @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
            String selValue= (String)lv.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Selected Item = "+selValue, 1000).show();

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }


    }
```

**and this is its respective xml file**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:entries="@array/courses">

        </ListView>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Start your logcat in Eclipse, terminal or download apps like 'log collector' on your phone. If something crashes, there is a log. If you post that im sure it will tell you what's going wrong

Comment: change your btnClick.setOnClickListener(this) to button1.setOnClickListener(this);..then it will work..

Answer (score 3):

We need your LogCat stack trace to be able to help you better. However this is what I see wrong at the moment:

```
 btnClick.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Will give a `NullPointerException` since you never did `findViewById()` for `btnClick`, only for `button1`.

**Also**, btnClick doesn't actually exist in your xml layout file, it seems you decided to use `button1` instead.

So either change the `OnClickListener` so you're using `button1`

```
button1.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Or  make a new button with the id btnClick in your xml. Then in your code, after `setContentView()` add this line:

```
 btnClick = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnClick);
```

Comment: thanq so much i did not realise that

Comment: i changed it but still i am getting the same problem

Comment: @user1938214 If it is still crashing, you will have to update the code in your question and *also* attach a LogCat stack trace so we can see what is going on.

Comment: @user1938214 if your issue is resolved, it would be appreciated if you'd accept the answer. If not, as I wrote before, update your question so we can continue helping.

Answer (score 0):

button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

```
        btnClick.setOnClickListener(this);// btnClick is null
```

use

button1.setOnClickListener(this);